# How to have combinations that match requirements in R

Tags: r

I have dataframe with courses and the number of hours the course take for a year. I also have another dataframe with teachers which can have 4 different profiles : "Perm", "Vac", "temp", "prom".

The amount of hours teach a year (the sum of all hours) must be given by at least 90% of ("Perm" + "Vac" + temp), 50% of ("Vac"+ "temp") and 20% of "temp".

Is it possible to have combinations of which profile should teach which course to match the requirements ?

```
Course    Hours    combination1    combination2
course1   200      ?               ? 
course2   50       ?               ?   
course3   150      ?               ?
course4   220      ?               ?   
course5   25       ?               ?
```

Comment: tischana, please no. When you asked [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60614199/r-how-to-have-combinations-that-match-requirements) (no improvements), it was requested that you improve it. Two links were provided, and both links give good advice on how to set up questions so that it is more likely (and easier) for somebody to answer it. Don't ignore our suggestions, and most certainly don't ask the same *exact* question with no changes, no improvements, ignoring our suggestions.

Comment: Please read those links ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info)), then re-pose the question with more effort and understanding.